# Can EGit revert a merge commit?

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, jgit, git-revert

When I try to revert a merge commit using EGit 4.1.1 I get the following error:

[image]

Using Git on the bash, I can do the following `git revert -m 1 f28ce5817da19f61110a3b794dcde50ea72341e9` and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the error message, apparently EGit cannot revert merge commits (i.e. commits with more than one parent).

The equivalent for `-m 1`, a dialog that asks you to select the mainline commit, for example, is missing.

You may want to [open an enhancement request for EGit](https://eclipse.org/egit/support/) to support reverting commits with more than one parent.

Comment: ... and in the meantime, "the command line." *(Which, for whatever reason, is what I wind up using **most** of the time ...)*  Luv lots of things about Eclipse, but to me its interface to `git` is, *ahh,* "very tedious."